# serializable interface

Tags: java

I  have a class that implements `java.io.Serializable` interface.So all the variables in that class is serilaizable. But i want to make some of the variables are should not serializable. Is it possible?

thanks,
Ravi

Comment: Just now i accept some of the answers of 22 questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark those variables as `transient`.

e.g.

```
class A implements Serializable{
    int a;
    transient int b;
}
```

When an object of `A` is serialized, the transient field b will not be serialized.

Comment: Thanks Grey..But any other way?

Comment: What's wrong with `transient`? How else would you want to do it?

Comment: You can write your own custom readObject and writeObject and serialize what you like how you like. But one keyword is simpler.

Comment: or maybe `java.io.Externalizable`?

Comment: Peter Lawrey: You should be always calling `defaultReadObject`, `defaultWriteObject`, `getFields` or `putFields` (might have got the names wrong - compiler will tell you) at the start of your `readObject`/`writeObject`. kalyaniRavi: There is another way involving a `static final` field name `serialPersistentFields` (something like that - if you misspell it, the compiler will not tell you!).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `transient` (why not?), you can implement [Externalizable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) and implement your own protocol:

```
public class Spaceship implements Externalizable {

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // ...
    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        // ...
    }

}
```

If that's too extreme, maybe you just want to customize the serialization a bit?  Keep implementing `Serializable` and implement your own `writeObject` and `readObject` methods.

Here's a bunch of examples: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variable a ***transient*** one and can look the article below for completely understanding the Serializable Interface

http://www.codingeek.com/java/io/object-streams-serialization-deserialization-java-example-serializable-interface/